# Is there a way to write a UDEV rule against a pseudo terminal?

Tags: linux, systemd, udev

I would like to create a systemd service unit file which has a `Requires=` and `After=` dependency on a psudeo terminal created by another service.

[This site](https://github.com/liquidctl/liquidctl/blob/main/docs/linux/making-systemd-units-wait-for-devices.md) describes how to do this for a real device by adding `TAG+=systemd` to a UDEV rule. So something like the following will generate a systemd device unit file which another service can depend on:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNEL=="ttyUSB0", PROGRAM="/etc/udev/usbtty.sh %k", SYMLINK+="ttyMyDev,OWNER="mydev", TAG+="systemd"
```

This will create a symlink at `/dev/ttyMyDev` to a USB TTY device, as well as have systemd create a `dev-ttyMyDev.device` unit.

However, for emulating virtual devices, we have a service which will create a pseudo terminal instead using the [posix_openpt(3) I/F](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_openpt.3.html). I'd like this service to also be able to create a new UDEV rules file in `/run/udev/rules.d` and to then have systemd be able to create a `dev-ttyMyVirtualDev.device` unit file.

However, I can't figure out how to get UDEV to recognize the device. For example, if I run the following `socat` command it will create a `/dev/pts/4` pseudo terminal:

```
$ sudo socat -d -d PTY,waitslave,echo=0,raw TCP-LISTEN:11313,reuseaddr,fork
2022/10/11 12:33:18 socat[24833] N PTY is /dev/pts/4
```

But I can't query it with `udevadm info`:

```
haz@haz-tower:/sys/devices/virtual/tty/ptmx$ udevadm info /dev/pts/4
Unknown device, --name=, --path=, or absolute path in /dev/ or /sys expected.
```

So I don't know what to put in the `KERNEL==` field of the UDEV rules file.

Does UDEV just not have the ability to trigger on the create of pseudo terminals?

Comment: I'm in the same boat :( I think it might be better to ask this question in the Unix & Linux forum though.